# $\int \frac{e^x+1}{(e^x\sin x+\cos x)(e^x\cos x-\sin x)}$

Tags: integration

I'm stuck on my last exercise. Could you help?
$$\int \frac{e^x+1}{(e^x\sin x+\cos x)(e^x\cos x-\sin x)} \ dx$$

Comment: @O.L. very sure.

Comment: +1  welcome to SE .this is your first question so appreciate it but after asking the question show some effort from your side

Comment: @cruise for some exercises you either know the way or you do nothing. I don't know the way. Integration by parts? Variable change? Nothing seems feasible.

Comment: Partial fractions might be an option here (note the product that we have in the denominator). Maybe give that a try.

Comment: @cruise: No, partial fractions doesn't work well here.

Comment: I highly doubt whether this function is integrable. Wolfram Alpha can also not find an expression for it. See here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%5Cfrac%7Be%5Ex%2B1%7D%7B%28e%5Ex%5Csin+x%2B%5Ccos+x%29%28e%5Ex%5Ccos+x-%5Csin+x%29%7D++dx

Comment: Mathematica doesnt either. Very rarely does Mathematica not find a function for a Integrable term. Are you absolutely sure you dont have a typo?

Comment: This is what Mathematica gives me @CBenni. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=des740&s=5

Comment: @cruise, it assumes that sinx and cosx are constants. With Mathematica, I was able to deduce a form of this expression made up of a sum of 4 small fractions, none of which is integrable

Comment: @CBenni Alright, I have to admit that I am not that familiar with Mathematica. I just thought I might give it a try. I think however that we can then conclude that this function is simply not integrable and thus the question is faulty.

Comment: This is what I get: http://mathb.in/4986